# How to log all Magento 2 SQL queries?

Tags: magento2, database, performance

Want to get all Sql queries during the page load.

can any one help me on How to log all Magento 2 SQL queries ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your app/etc/di.xml, replace the line:

`<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\Quiet"/>`

with

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File"/>
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File">
  <arguments>
      <argument name="logAllQueries" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
      <argument name="debugFile" xsi:type="string">log/sql.log</argument>
  </arguments>
</type>
```

Flush Magento cache (in backend, or by executing `bin/magento cache:flush`) after this.

Log file is located here: **var/log/sql.log**

Comment: I am not sure, but this might not work anymore in 2.2 ; at least it doesnt in my case.

Comment: In latest version of magento (i'm checking on 2.3.1) You can use this: php bin/magento dev:query-log:enable --include-all-queries=1 --query-time-threshold=1 --include-call-stack=false (as mentioned by @Felix below)

Answer (score 50):

```
bin/magento dev:query-log:enable
```

.
(copied my answer from [Magento 2 log database queries](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107361/magento-2-log-database-queries/201517#201517))

Comment: This is the correct answer for Magento 2.2 and beyond. As mentioned in the [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/logging.html#database-logging) page, the queries get logged to `var/debug/db.log` (not a file in `var/log`)

Answer (score 8):

Alternative (to the answer of Siju Joseph),

if you don't want to change your magento config, you can also configure mysql itself: activate slow.log and set it to 0 seconds.

Therefore edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set `slow_query_log` to 'on' and `long_query_time` to '0'.

This will result in all mysql queries getting logged.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: in the my.cnf. Just set slow_query_log  to 'on' and  long_query_time to '0'