# How to log query for cart event?

Tags: cart, magento2.4, query

I want to see the mysql query when adding a product to the cart. I have referred this link, [How to log all Magento 2 SQL queries?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162772/how-to-log-all-magento-2-sql-queries) but I need query only for cart.

How to get the query for cart events? Can anyone please guide?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at adding some logging to the `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct` method.

If you want to log the MySQL commands server-side, you might have to add logging at a very low level. After adding items to the quote entity, the quote will be saved to the database via `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::save` method. This method is used to save all entities to the database though, so you'll have to be very defensive in your logging etc.