# Magento 2: How to Enable Query Logging?

Tags: magento2, query, log

We can do db logging via

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File" />
```

But it's Module Wise.

How can we do whole Magento wise (Fronend/Backend) or display all queries at end of page?

Comment: where did you add this preference? It should work if you add this in the global `di.xml` in one of your modules

Comment: In my custom module @Marius

Comment: it should work like that. The preferences are global, not module specific.

Comment: So if I only add in my custom Module then it works for whole Magento?

Comment: It should. Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/107361/146